# Find date upon which defined age in seconds is reached

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I am attempting to write a program that

1. takes a certain number of seconds (say 1000000000), then
2. takes a given date (for example one's birthday) and
3. then determines when (at which given date) this age in number of seconds has been reached.

Certainly, the program should recognize if that age in number of seconds is in the past. 
But even before building a check for this, the code runs into problems.

After receiving error message I tried changing parameter name from month to umonth in the input stage. That brought no difference.

```
from datetime import datetime

seconds = int(input("seconds: "))

year = int(input("year: "))
month = int(input("month: "))
day = int(input("day: "))

#Calculate time in seconds between now and the day of birth
date = (datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day) - datetime(seconds)).total_seconds()

print("You will be {} seconds old on {} old.".format(seconds, date))
```

I am still dabbling with the datetime library.

I received a TypeError from python3.

*"TypeError: Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found"*

**Edit:**

Following suggestions in the comments, I modified the code for using a new method, to convert a date into seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime

#seconds = int(input("seconds: "))
seconds = 1000000000

#year = int(input("year: "))
#month = int(input("month: "))
#day = int(input("day: "))
year = 1987
month = 9
day = 11

date = datetime.datetime(year,month,day)

#Calculate time in seconds between now and the day of birth
(date.total_seconds(datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)) - seconds)

print("You will be {} seconds old on {} old.".format(seconds, date))
```

That yields an *AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'*

I am aware I dont know exactly how to use datetime library.
Working through the docs to understand.

But still, those things seem trivial to achieve.
Perhaps someone can explain.

The goal is, as before, to take a number of seconds and a date of birth.
And to see when, from the date of birth on, the number of seconds will be reached.

Comment: `datetime(seconds)` is the problem here, why do you do that?

Comment: Trying to deduct the number of seconds received from input from the date of birth specified.

Comment: Yes that lines causes the error `"TypeError: Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found"`, why not just subtract seconds instead of converting to datetime?

Comment: How do I get the date entered converted into seconds then?

Plus, there is to be sanity checks, for when the date is reached.
Whether is has been reached in the past. 
And if reached in the past when.

Comment: `date.total_seconds()` for date to seconds. for sanity checks you can think on your logic accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

You are receiving the above error because you already used import datetime. No need of writing datetime.datetime. You can directly use datetime(year, month, day).